# Laravel: How to show images from storage of a project to another project in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, e-commerce

I am making an ecommerce site in laravel 8. Currently, I am building it on local computer but later the project will be on domain.com and seller.domain.com.

For that reason one project has been divided into two sharing the same DB. Seller will upload images of the product on seller.domain.com and this product will be listed on domain.com.

Since, DB is same so I can fetch every details of the product but the images are being saved in another project so I can't fetch it.

Is there anyways to fetch images from a  project to my another project.

I think it is possible to do with api's but I am trying this way.

Comment: why are you dividing the project?? you can use the same project with subdomain routing for seller. and if you use two different projects, you can't use `asset` /  `storage` helper.. you have to give the full path for files. in that case make a helper function that will add the base url with the file path specified in the db. and simply by changing the base url in the helper, you can change the domain any time.

Comment: I didn't knew if it was possible to make subdomain from the same projects for seller. Can you help me more by telling how to do it or can you give me some references 

Comment: laravel sub domain routing [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-subdomain-routing).. let me know if you want a full answer.

Comment: If you don't mind at all. You can brief me in full answer. By the way I am going through the documentation and I will have to combine both the project into one. And thank you for your help dude. I assume the documentation will help me but still if you can give me best answer I would really like to hear it. Once again Jazakallah

Comment: the answer won't be compatible with this question and hence i am not answering. i hope the doc is enough to help you.. if you face any problem implementing this, ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks for all the help done above. Your comments helped me a lot and I managed different subdomains in a same folder. Although I came late here for the thanksgiving.